# Prisma adding null records even if restraint is broken

Tags: graphql, prisma

I've created a one-to-one relationship between a User and a Profile. When trying to run a createProfile mutation and connecting the user in playground, I rightfully get error messages saying:

"You provided an ID that was not a valid MongoObjectId"
or
"The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'UserProfile' between Profile and User"
or
"No Node for the model User with value 5d67f8a724aa9a0007997f1b for id found."

All of these makes sense when I tinker with the input. Also when I place the correct ID it works fine as well. However, when querying for Profiles, I get the total number of requests that I've made. I see the one that worked and also a bunch of null records.

I don't see an area where I can tinker with the resolvers, but even then I find it kinda strange that if a mutation fails, the database still inserts an empty record. I'm using Prisma with the mongo connector if that helps.

Here's my schema:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  profile: Profile @relation(name: "UserProfile")
}

type Profile {
  id: ID! @id 
  handle: String!
  experience: [Experience!] 
  education: [Education!] 
  user: User! @unique @relation(name: "UserProfile", link: INLINE)
}
```

And the mutation I'm trying after already creating a user

```
mutation createProfile{
    createProfile(
    data:{ 
      user:{connect:{id:"5d67f8a724aa9a0007997f1b"}}
      handle:"handleIt"
      experience: {
        create:
          [
            { title: "Web Application Programmer" company:"HHH" from:"2018"}
            { title: "Web Administrator" company:"TDC" from:"2017"}
          ]
      }
    }
  )
  {
    id
  }
}
```